# cx_Oracle on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with Existing Windows Oracle Installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I'm running Oracle Database 12c 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit on Windows, but I would like to be able to use cx_Oracle through WSL.

When running a Python script in WSL that uses cx_Oracle, I receive the following error:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot
>   be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory."

I read [this article](https://medium.com/@arunkundgol/how-to-setup-oracle-instant-client-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-cccee61d5b0b) which mentions downloading Instant Client for Linux, but I don't know if that is still required if I already have Oracle Database 12c Client on Windows. There is a part in the article about creating symbolic links, one of them being libclntsh.so.  Is there a way to link my Oracle 12c client on Windows to be used with cx_Oracle in WSL?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess you would need the Linux client in order to use it within WSL. I'd certainly try that at least!